# How to set the Boolean value as false in Java Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am practicing Java and Spring Boot.

Actually my idea is if we send json delete request means it should change details in the database  as inactive instead of deleting that data.

for Example if I want to delete the student record. Base on student ID as 1 means it should change the student status as inactive instead of deleting that record.

In spring boot controller I have a delete method.

Codes are below for your understanding:

**Controller:**

```
@DeleteMapping("v1/student/delete/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteStudentDetails(@PathVariable("id") Integer getId) {
    studentService.deleteStudentdetails(getId);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("STUDENT RECORD HAS BEEN DELETED !!!", HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

studentService = is a service class which sending the information from controller to service.

deleteStudentdetails = is a method in service class.

**Service class method**

```
public void deleteStudentdetails(Integer getId) {

    Optional<StudentDetails> studentIdDetails = studentRepo.findById(getId); // getting info from DB
    StudentDetails studentIsdetail = studentIdDetails.get(); 

    if (studentIsdetail.getActive() == false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Student is Already inActive!!"); 
    }

    studentIsdetail.setActive(false); // Here I want to change the Active Status from True to false


}
```

Here I am changing the values in the Database by retrieving the student ID which is already existing in the DB.

STUDENT_ID      ACTIVE      BOARD_ID
60  TRUE    STATEBOARD

116 TRUE    STATEBOARD //here want to change the status as False

120 FALSE   STATEBOARD

Comment: I don't see you saving `studentIsdetail` into the database after modifying it. Is perhaps the problem that when you try to set a student as inactive, the corresponding value in the ACTIVE column of the database table does not change? Because if that's the case, it looks like not saving `studentIsdetail` could be the cause.

Comment: I tried this but not working - Unable to save this 
         studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail.setActive(false));

Comment: `studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail.setActive(false));` probably doesn't even compile, unless `setActive()` returns the instance of `StudentDetails` it modified. `studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail);` after `studentIsdetail.setActive(false);` should compile and work fine, though.

Comment: @Hariprasath `.save` will propagate the changes in object to the database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You never save studentIsdetail into the database after modifying.
So just add `studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail);` after calling `studentIsdetail.setActive(false);` and it should work:

```java
public void deleteStudentdetails(Integer getId) {
    Optional<StudentDetails> studentIdDetails = studentRepo.findById(getId); // getting info from DB
    StudentDetails studentIsdetail = studentIdDetails.get(); 

    if (!studentIsdetail.getActive()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Student is Already inActive!!"); 
    }

    studentIsdetail.setActive(false);
    studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail);
}
```

---

And I recommend that you check if you get a result to avoid exceptions:

```java
public void deleteStudentdetails(Integer getId) {
    Optional<StudentDetails> studentIdDetails = studentRepo.findById(getId); // getting info from DB
    if (studentIsdetail.isEmpty()) {
        // handle e.g. throw exception or just return (with return:)
        return;
    }
    StudentDetails studentIsdetail = studentIdDetails.get(); 

    if (!studentIsdetail.getActive()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Student is Already inActive!!"); 
    }

    studentIsdetail.setActive(false);
    studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail);
}
```

For this you can also use `Optional#ifPresent`:

```java
public void deleteStudentdetails(Integer getId) {
    Optional<StudentDetails> studentIdDetails = studentRepo.findById(getId); // getting info from DB

    studentIdDetails.ifPresent((studentIsdetail) -> {
        if (!studentIsdetail.getActive()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Student is Already inActive!!"); 
        }

        studentIsdetail.setActive(false);
        studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail);
    });
}
```

Comment: public void deleteStudentdetails(Integer getId) {

  Optional<StudentDetails> studentIdDetails = studentRepo.findById(getId);

  StudentDetails studentIsdetail = studentIdDetails.get();

  if (studentIsdetail.getActive() == false || studentIsdetail.getStudentId() != getId) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Student Status is Already inActive!!!");
  }

  studentIsdetail.setActive(false);
  studentRepo.save(studentIsdetail);
 }             
I am trying to check getId which is JSON request with studentIsdetail.getStudentId() which is available on the DB
  
but its not working why?

Comment: That's a different problem and I need more information to help you there. So if my answer solved the problem problem discussed in this post please consider accepting the answer.